# Using bash to jump around to common directories quickly

Tags: linux, bash

I've got a few "favorite" folders in my directory tree that I like to jump around to. I could add an `alias` in my `.bash_profile` for each of the directories and map each one to one of my favorite directories to get around to them quickly. But this gets a little tedious and I don't want to have to do it every time I want to add a favorite folder.

So I'm wondering if there might be a better, more efficient way. For example, I'm imagining some kind of script that would look at your current directory, flag it as a favorite, and create an alias for you.

Does any such animal exist?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a really good solution: https://github.com/wting/autojump

This utility remembers which directories you visit the most and guesses which directory to jump to based on the argument you pass to it.

So `cd /my/long/path/to/my/directory` becomes `j direct`

Comment: Can you summarise what it does or why it looks really good? Link-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

There's [z](https://github.com/rupa/z), a similar tool to `autojump` proposed by [StevieD](https://superuser.com/users/164975/stevied). From the provided description:

> Tracks your **most used directories**, based on '*frecency*'.
>
> After  a  short  learning  phase, `z` will take you to the most
>   '*frecent*' directory that matches ALL of the regexes given on the
>   command line, in order.
>
> For example, `z foo bar` would match `/foo/bar` but not `/bar/foo`.

On the concept of *frecency*:

> *Frecency* is a portmanteau of '**recent**' and '**frequency**'. It is a
>   weighted rank  that depends on how often and how recently something
>   occurred.
>
> To `z`, a directory that has low ranking but has been  accessed 
>   recently will  quickly  have  higher rank than a directory accessed
>   frequently a long time ago.

If the install howto provided by the author doesn't seem clear to you (as it didn't for me), you can check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250012/how-do-i-install-z-script) AskUbuntu answer for somewhat more comprehensive install instructions.

Also, I learned about `z` from [this](https://hashnode.com/post/what-are-your-top-cli-tools-hacks-for-productivity-cinov8y4w00njxh53j2w9wfy4) post on Hashnode about useful terminal hacks for productivity.